# Can you explain me how Continuous Integration works?

Tags: continuous-integration

I wish to use Continuous Integration, but I'm little lost with Ant, Jenkins, CruiseControl, Phing, PHPUnderControl, etc...

What is really Continuous Integration?

I'm developping PHP application using Zend Framework, and it sounds great to deploy easily and tests piece of code.

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't this be answered by googling "continuous integration"?  There are numerous good results.

Comment: Not really because a lot of things are mixed around CI, and I don't know all the concept around to actually understand what is CI (not the things around it)

Answer (score 10):

Continuous integration is a process that automatically performs a build whenever a check-in/commit occurs.  This allows integration problems to be identified ASAP and makes it easier to identify who is responsible for the problem.  As a bonus, continuous integration requires a completely automated build process which makes it much easier for anyone to replicate the development environment on their machine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand a lot more now, CI is just an interface which runs scripts to test modification when committing, automated build is something different, I though it was used for deployment only, something like continuous integration from dev platform to production platform, but I understand now why it applies to every project.